# Set Http header using Jboss6.1

Tags: jboss6.x, cache-control

Is there any way to set HttpHeader using Jboss6.1's configuration file. These configuration is applicable to a whole project.

I want to set bellow properties in Jboss6.1 server using its configuration file.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

I tried it with domain.xml but nothing works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't complicate yourself. If you want every response has this header configuration, create your own filter to do this. This way you won't be coupled to JBoss and get what you want.

Here you have a filter sample:

```
package your.package;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

          @Override
          public void destroy() {
          }

          @Override
          public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                  HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                  hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
                  hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                  hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
                  chain.doFilter(req, res);
          }

          @Override
          public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
          }
}
```

then you only have to configure it into your `web.xml` more or less this way:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This mapping is valid for all request, but you can adapt it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The project doesn't have any java code. It's in angularjs and jboss is used as Webserver

Comment: Well, you tagged this question as Java ... But any case, I don't see the problem. If you are using a J2EE container you can add a filter, and it solves your problem. And what I think it is more important, this way, your are not coupling to JBoss, this is a compatible solution with any J2EE and/or Servlet container.

Comment: @Nidhin, did you try my answer? It is valid for your problem, and it will address your needs although you don't have java code.

Comment: Java code does not works for me, any way it's a good answer so awarded bounty. Thanks